# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener

I have one button element in a relatively simple HTML file. I'm trying to add an event listener, but I keep getting errors, and I'm not sure why: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'addEventListener'`

I am trying to learn the 'addEventListener' method, but I'm not understanding what's wrong with what I'm doing:

HTML:

`<button>guess</button>`

JS:

```
var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

myButton.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);

var doSomething = function(e){
    console.log('I was clicked!');

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

Thank you to those who helped.

**In conclusion for any other newbies that might be having this problem:**

1. When you use `document.getElementsByTagName()` or any other method that returns a NodeList, you have to specify which node you want to manipulate.
2. Make sure you add the event listener *after* the function has been declared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName('button')` returns a list, not an element. You need to add your EventListener to the first element in that list.

Try:

```
var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a very simple, straight-to-the-point explanation, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a list of elements, a nodeList, and `addEventListener` only works on one single element at a time, so it's good form to iterate, that way you won't get screwed if you decided to have more than one element, and you'll get used to writing event handlers this way

```
var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

var doSomething = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('I was clicked!');
};

for (var i=myButton.length; i--;) {
    myButton[i].addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I wish I could choose all of your answers. This works too, and it definitely doesn't have any hard-coded stuff. Thank you though, I will probably use your method later when I get into more complicated things. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
```